# Why is my Tutum service starting then within 2 seconds stopping with a container status "die" command?

Tags: docker, tutum

I'm running a custom reposository from Docker Hub on Tutum and trying to start a service.  I get a Service Start, but then 1-2 seconds, it receives a Container status die command.  I can't figure out why.

```
Received event 'die' from node 31b3f894-a0b9-494e-bca0-9212b642dd15.node.dockerapp.io for container api-1: Running
Changing container state from 'Running' to 'Stopped'
Checking triggers
Container has no triggers
```

Comment: Tutum was acquired by Docker and is now called Docker Cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer back from Docker Cloud (formerly Tutum) support.

> When the process started inside a container exits for whatever reason,
>   the container is then considered "exited". Docker cloud shows this
>   service as "stopped" once it sees the container is no longer running.

So this particular container is trying to connect to a database (which I don't have connected again) so it fails, therefore that is why it tells the service to shut down.